# Cross-platform tool to parallel building of C/C++ based projects

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, makefile, cmake, qmake

I'm looking for a tool that able to provide building of C/C++-based projects in parallel/multithreaded mode.
Looking for cross-platform solution between Windows and Linux.

Cross-platform building requires usage of CMake or QMake or CLang.

Could anybody suggest cross-platform parallel build tool that could be used with CMake/QMake/Clang?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, are you asking for [make -j](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/make/make_47.html#SEC46)??

Comment: Do you mean distributed (you mentioned IncrediBuild) or parallel but on the same machine ? CMake only takes care of generating projects. It is then up Visual Studio or make, or your platform's build tool to support parallel build. For example you can tell make to use mutiple processes with the `-jX` option where X is the number of subprocesses to use.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ. Yes! That's what I'm looking for. But, if I go to use CMake to generate project files, is there way to put "-j" flag through CMake? Thanks.

Comment: François Moisan, will be good for parallel on the same machine.

Comment: @AlexanderBorodulya. Ok, well I'm not sure you really want to set that flag from CMake itself. CMake should only take care of generating projects/makefiles. The way you invoke make is another story.

Comment: Ninja is supported by CMake since 2.8. It faster than make and it uses multiple cores by default.